# Why is my use of predict in r not working - should be very simple case

Tags: r, syntax, lm

So I'm having some trouble getting r to actually predict given a very, very simple linear model. Using the following,

```
> x=1:10
> y=1:10*2
> lm(y~x)
```

we get the corect answer, namely, y is twice x. But when I do,

```
predict(lm(y~x),newdata=2.5)
```

I just get

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

What is going on?

Comment: did you mean `predict(lm(x~y)...)` or did you mean `lm(y~x)` as in the original example?

Comment: the `newdata` variable expects a class data.frame, so just ignores your integer input and outputs the values of the dependent variable.

Comment: So r does not parse function inputs by order?

Comment: In this case it should probably return an error if it doesn't like your input, but R silently does something else without telling you.

Comment: Fantastic :-/ At least I know what to send in now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `newdata` parameter should be a `data.frame` with column names matching the names used as covariates. So the correct case is

```
predict(lm(x~y),newdata=data.frame(y=2.5))
```

or

```
predict(lm(y~x),newdata=data.frame(x=2.5))
```

depending on which way you wanted to do the regression.